# using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-plugins

using [jquery-ui-map](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/)

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': new google.maps.LatLng(3.162456,21.09375), 'zoom': 2, 'streetViewControl': false, 'callback': 
    function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('loadHTML', 'microformat', '.importers', function(markerOpts, node, index) {
            var clone = $(node);
            // We have to add a callback in the addmarker method so we can access the marker just added
            var name = $(node).find('.name');   
            var icon = $(node).find('.icon');   
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', jQuery.extend({ 'title': name.html(), 'icon':new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon.html())}, markerOpts), function(map, marker) {
                $(name).click( function() {
                $(marker).triggerEvent('click');
                    return false;
                }); 
            }).click(function() {
                $('.reveal').removeClass('reveal');
                $(this).get(0).map.panTo($(this).get(0).position);                 
                $(clone).toggleClass('reveal');
                //need to wait till pan has complete before doing zoom!            

                });
              });
            }
        });
    });
```

at the moment when you click on a market it pans to its position

what i want to do is also zoomin, i've tried just adding

```
$(this).get(0).map.setZoom(5, true);
```

but this means the pan does not work it just jumps straight to the zoom level, how do i get it to fire the $(this).get(0).map.setZoom(5, true);       after the panning is done?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker').click(function() {
    $(this).get(0).map.panTo($(this).get(0).position);
    var self = $(this).get(0);
    setTimeout(function() { self.map.setCenter(self.position); self.map.setZoom(15); }, 2000);
});
```

This would be the easy way of setting the zoom after the pan.

Comment: Thanks that worked fine, are you the creator of the plugin? can i ask you a few questions? i'm trying to display markers around the world and then have a dropdown so you can filter by country, i then want the map to pan and zoom to that country. can this be done using the plugin?

Comment: @Adam-Wright
If you don't have that many markers you could always iterate through the markers and hide/show by country code. ie
`$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'country':'sv', 'bound':false, 'position':latlng1, 'title': 'Sweden' }, function(map, marker) {
     console.log(marker.country);
    });
     
    var markers = $('#map_canvas').gmap('getMarkers');
    $.each(markers, function(key, value) { 
     if ( value.country != "sv" ) {
      value.setVisible(false);
     }
});`

Comment: @Adam-Wright: If you have alot of markers I would consider clearing all markers and import the country markers with JSON for each filtering, ie

`$('#map_canvas').gmap('loadJSON', 'URL', 'country=sv', function(i, m) {
       $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'bound':true, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng) } );
      });
`

Comment: @Adam-Wright: Set bound:true on the addMarker function and the map will calculate the zoom itself, eg one marker = zoom ~13, two markers (one in Canada and one in Germany) = zoom ~3

Comment: @Adam-Wright: If you have any questions pls post in the [forum](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-map-discuss).

Comment: @Adam-Wright: Btw. in the timeout function you should have self.map.setCenter(self.position); (see updated answer) otherwise you might be off with the zoom.

Comment: I uploaded an example: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/google-maps-jquery-filtering.html